# Is good to use React.useMemo or React.useCallback inside component props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization, react-usememo, react-usecallback

I was thinking about how to code TailwindCSS cleaner in React. Since Tailwind is utility-first, it makes us inevitably end up with components (ex: `className="w-full bg-red-500"`). So, I tried to create a utility like this:
`utils/tailwind.ts`

```
const tw = (...classes: string[]) => classes.join(' ')
```

and call it inside:
`components/Example.tsx`

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import tw from '../utils/tailwind'

const Example = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e: any) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <div
        className={tw(
          'w-full',
          'h-full',
          'bg-red-500'
        )}
      >
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But, it will cause `tw()` to be re-called as always as `text` state is updated.

So, I decided to wrap `tw()` function using `useMemo` to prevent re-call since the `tw()` always returns the same value. But the code is like this:

```
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react'
import tw from '../utils/tailwind'

const Example = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e: any) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <div
        className={useMemo(() => tw(
          'w-full',
          'h-full',
          'bg-red-500'
        ), [])}
      >
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is it correct or good practice if I put `useMemo` like that? Thank you  .

Comment: Calling it inside the JSX element syntax is the same as calling it before the `return` expression, storing the result in a temporary variable, and passing that as the attribute value. No difference. Of course the rules of hooks still apply, you can't do that in a conditional rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct or good practice if I put useMemo like that?

Short answer - `yes`.

Long answer - it depends. It depends on how heavy the operation is. In your particular case, joining a couple of *strings* may not be such *heavy* calculation to make the `useMemo` worth to be used - it's good to remember that `useMemo` *memoizes* stuff and it takes memory.

Consider example below. In the first case, without `useMemo`, the `tw` function will be *called* with every `App` re-render, to calculate new `className`. However, if `useMemo` is used (with empty *dependency array*), `tw` **will not** be called and new `className` **will not** be calculated even if the `App` re-renders, due to the basic *memoization*. It will be called only **once**, on component mount.

Conclusion - it's a good practice to use `useMemo`, but rather for heavy operations, like mapping or reducing huge arrays.

```
export default function App() {
  const [_, s] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={tw(false, 'w-full', 'h-full', 'bg-red-500')}>div1</div>
      <div
        className={useMemo(
          () => tw(true, 'w-full', 'h-full', 'bg-red-500'),
          [],
        )}
      >
        div2
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => s(Math.random())}>re-render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-liskov-tfm72c?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you `@kind user` . So, if the project will be bigger and because `useMemo` takes memory also the `tw()` function always only joins strings, so which one do you prefer? use `useMemo` or not? Thank you  .

Comment: @mnrendra Personally I would not use useMemo on joining strings. Rather as I mentioned above - on mapping or reducing huge arrays. But still it depends on how many elements you are joining. If it's about hundreds - it's worthy for sure. If just a couple - it's not. (Comment edited)

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that React will re-render the component every time it's state changes. (each time you setText).

If you want to prevent that from happening, then see if you really need this re-render hence what do you really need the input text for?

you do not HAVE to use state here to use the input value.
you could call another function on change which will not update the state, and use the input value there for whatever you need.
for example:

```
const Example = () => {

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    const text = e.target.value

    // do something with text
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e: any) => onInputChange(e)} />
      <div
        className={useMemo(() => tw(
          'w-full',
          'h-full',
          'bg-red-500'
        ), [])}
      >
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```